# How to persist state between different Flask endpoint calls?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, twilio

I am writing a simple web-application to initiate conference calling using Flask and Twilio API. The way Twilio API works is, you call a number using a Twilio number; when the call is answered, Twilio will call a callback URL you have specified earlier. When the callback is called, the currently active call will be added to an active conference room. So the problem I have with Flask is how to pass an active conference session between endpoint functions.

For example;

```
class ConferenceSession(object):

   def __init__(self, config):
       self._conf_session = SomeTwilioAPI()

   def dial_attendee(self, number):
      # dial the attendee  
      SomeTwilioAPI.call(number)

   def add_attendee(self):
      if self._conf_session:
          self._conf_session.SomeTwilioAPI()

# flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.route('/conference')
def conference():
    for participants in request['participants']:
    return conf_session.dial_attendee(participants')

@app.route('/answered')
def answered()
    conf_session.add_attendee()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = ConfConfig()
    conf_session = ConferenceSession(config)
    app.run()
```

Right now this works. But my project is not packaged properly. And also I am using sort of global variable `conf_session`. So my question how can enclose `Flask` app inside a class, so the variable `conf_session` can be accessed without using a global variable? Sorry I can't provide the MVP because a lot of unrelated code for the context.

Comment: Take a look at the doc on session. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions. You can set the session in one endpoint, and check for it in the next endpoint

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the doc on session [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions). You can set `conf_session` in one endpoint and access it in the next endpoint.

Something along this line:

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/check_session')
def check():
    if 'conf_session' in session:
        # do something here

@app.route('/set_session')
def set_session():
    # set the conf_session here
    conf_session = call_to_twilio()
    session['conf_session'] = conf_session
```